# Replace single quotes with double quotes in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a directory full of SAS label files.

The label files have space, single quote, space, single quote in each file:

```
VAR1 = ' 'SOME LABEL' '
```

I want a bash script that will replace these single quotes with double quotes so that I end up with:

```
VAR1 = "SOME LABEL"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have this test file:

```
$ cat file
VAR1 = ' 'SOME LABEL' '
```

To replace sinqle-quote-space-single-quote with double-quote whereever it appears, we can used sed:

```
$ sed "s/' '/\"/g" file
VAR1 = "SOME LABEL"
```

If the above produces the output that you want, then you may want to change the file in-place.  This can be done using:

```
sed -i "s/' '/\"/g" file  # linux
sed -i "" "s/' '/\"/g" file  # BSD/OSX
```

To make the replacement on **all** files in the current directory:

```
sed -i "s/' '/\"/g" *  # linux
sed -i "" "s/' '/\"/g" *  # BSD/OSX
```

#### Example

```
$ cat file
VAR1 = ' 'SOME LABEL' '
$ sed -i "s/' '/\"/g" *  # linux
$ cat file
VAR1 = "SOME LABEL"
```

Comment: Tried this version on a linux machine sed -i "s/' '/\"/g" *  # linux. Every time I save the script it replaces the single quotes with double qoutes in vi.

Comment: @e_archiv1 I suggest starting with `sed "s/' '/\"/g" file`.  If that produces output that you like, then use `-i` to do the change-in-place.

Comment: @e_archiv1 I would use the mouse to copy and paste John1024's invocation `sed -i "s/' '/\"/g" *` straight onto the command line, and hit Return.  Or, if I wanted it in a script file, forget about vi, just say `cat > scriptfile` and copy and paste the text and type control-D.

Comment: I copied this sed -i "s/' '/\"/g" * directly to the command line, and nothing, maybe I am not able to use the "sed" command on my machine?

Comment: `sed` is included standard with linux.  Did you try `sed "s/' '/\"/g" file` (this does not change any files but shows what it would have done on the terminal)? (Replace `file` with the name of one of your files.)  If your files are long, use `sed "s/' '/\"/g" file | less`.  Tell what you see.

Comment: I submitted sed "s/' '/\"/g" file, using a file in my directory, and it repeated the file exactly as it was. The output still showed single quote space singe quote space. ' '.

Comment: @e_archiv1 Thanks.  `sed` will, of course, only make substitutions if   it finds an __exact__ match.  One of the problems of unicode is that there are many characters which look alike to humans but are completely different to computers.  So, on possibility is that the quote-space-quote that you see is using a non-standard quote.  Let's try a few things.  Run `sed "s/'/HELLO/" file | less`.  Does that change the single quotes?  If it doesn't, replace the single quote in the `sed` command with a copy-and-paste of the single quote (or whatever it is) from your file and run it again.  Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
for f in *
do
    sed "s/' '/\"/g" "$f" > "$f".new && mv "$f".new "$f"
done
```

(But batch-editing files in-place like this can be risky, so please, back up your files before trying it!)

Comment: Just use `-i` flag to do inplace edit, no need for creating temporary file on your own.

Comment: @e_archiv1 Sorry to hear that!  But now I *have* tested it, and it worked just fine for me, so it's a puzzle why it didn't for you.  (And I really don't understand how it could have blanked the files.)

Comment: @e_archiv1 I tried the `sed -i` recipe from John1024's answer, and it worked, too.

Comment: `-i` requires GNU sed, in BSD sed you have to specify a backup extension, even if it's empty: `-i''`

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
> cat t.sas
variable="vol1"
variable2="vol3"

sed -i '' "s/\"\(.*\)\"/\'\1\'/" *.sas
```

what this does is search all files in the directory matching *.sas and then search each file for the regular expression "*", it then replaces the "" with '' whilst inserting the test identified on the right hand side of the sed command.

result:

```
> cat t.sas
variable='vol1'
variable2='vol3'
```

thus...

```
sed -i '' "s/\'\(.*\)\'/\"\1\"/" *.sas

> cat t.sas
variable="vol1"
variable2="vol3"
```